# Amend Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I know this has been covered quite a lot. However, I haven't been able to fix my problem, despite visiting every Stackoverflow link that has something to do with changing label text.

I've tried using `StringVar()` and `.configure()` without any luck.

What I'm trying to do is, upon the user selecting the desired genre and clicking Display Movie(s) a string will be displayed with the movies available under the genre.

However, the issue I'm facing is that the labels keep overlapping each other, despite using .configure() to update the text, instead of creating another one on top.

Here is a small demonstration of what my application is currently doing:
Overlapping of Label

[image]

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import datetime

#
# Created by SAXAR on 04/12/2018.
#

timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()  # Creating a variable to use the date time library.

screens = ["Screen 1", "Screen 2", "Screen 3", "Screen 4", "Screen 5", "Screen 6"]

movies = {"Horror": ["The Nun", "Dracula Untold", "Feral", "Shin Godzilla", "Black Death"],
          "Action": ["Venom", "Robin Hood", "Aquaman", "Artemis Fowl", "The Predator"],
          "Drama": ["Creed", "Creed 2", "Outlaw King", "Peppermint", "Sicario: Day of the Soldado"],
          "Comedy": ["Step Brothers", "The Hangover", "Horrible Bosses", "The Other Guys", "Let's Be Cops"],
          "Sci-Fi": ["The Matrix", "Solaris", "Blade Runner", "Interstellar", "Sunshine"],
          "Romance": ["Ghost", "Sliding Doors", "50 Shades of Grey", "Titanic", "La La Land"]}



class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, Frame=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

    def updateHorror(self, event=None):
        selectedGenre = self.genreCombo.get()
        print(selectedGenre)
        return selectedGenre

    def createWidgets(self):
        # The heading for the application.
        Label(
            text="___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________").place(
            x=0, y=25)
        self.headingLabel = Label(text="Cinema Bookings")
        self.headingLabel.config(font=("Roboto", 12))
        self.headingLabel.place(x=10, y=10)

        Label(text="________").place(x=10, y=65)
        Label(text="TODAY").place(x=10, y=60)
        Label(text="________").place(x=10, y=42)

        Label(text="Genre: ").place(x=70, y=60)
        self.genreCombo = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(width=15, values=list(movies.keys()), state="readonly")
        self.genreCombo.current(0)
        self.genreCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.updateHorror)
        self.genreCombo.place(x=110, y=60)

        Label(
            text="___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________").place(
            x=0, y=85)


        Button(text="Display Movie(s)", command=self.createLabel).place(x=585, y=265, width=100)

    def createLabel(self, event=None):

        self.movieLabel = Label(text = "")
        self.movieLabel.place(x=60, y=160)
        self.movieLabel.configure(text=" | ".join(movies.get(self.updateHorror())))


w = 700
h = 300
x = 0
y = 0

app = Application()
app.master.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
app.master.title("Cinema Booking")
app.mainloop()
```

Excuse my poor coding. Most of it is previous work from last year's course work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you are creating the *movielabel* inside the `createLabel()` method. So, every time the button is clicked, a new *movielabel* is created, which overrides the previously generated label.

What you want is a single label and everytime the button is clicked, its text will change accordingly. So, you need to create the label in the `createWidgets()` function and just *configure* its text in the `createLabel` function.

Here is the working code.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk
import tkinter.messagebox
import datetime

timeNow = datetime.datetime.now()  # Creating a variable to use the date time library.

screens = ["Screen 1", "Screen 2", "Screen 3", "Screen 4", "Screen 5", "Screen 6"]

movies = {"Horror": ["The Nun", "Dracula Untold", "Feral", "Shin Godzilla", "Black Death"],
          "Action": ["Venom", "Robin Hood", "Aquaman", "Artemis Fowl", "The Predator"],
          "Drama": ["Creed", "Creed 2", "Outlaw King", "Peppermint", "Sicario: Day of the Soldado"],
          "Comedy": ["Step Brothers", "The Hangover", "Horrible Bosses", "The Other Guys", "Let's Be Cops"],
          "Sci-Fi": ["The Matrix", "Solaris", "Blade Runner", "Interstellar", "Sunshine"],
          "Romance": ["Ghost", "Sliding Doors", "50 Shades of Grey", "Titanic", "La La Land"]}

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, Frame=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.createWidgets()

    def updateHorror(self, event=None):
        selectedGenre = self.genreCombo.get()
        print(selectedGenre)
        return selectedGenre

    def createWidgets(self):
        # The heading for the application.
        Label(
            text="___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________").place(
            x=0, y=25)
        self.headingLabel = Label(text="Cinema Bookings")
        self.headingLabel.config(font=("Roboto", 12))
        self.headingLabel.place(x=10, y=10)

        Label(text="________").place(x=10, y=65)
        Label(text="TODAY").place(x=10, y=60)
        Label(text="________").place(x=10, y=42)

        Label(text="Genre: ").place(x=70, y=60)
        self.genreCombo = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(width=15, values=list(movies.keys()), state="readonly")
        self.genreCombo.current(0)
        self.genreCombo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.updateHorror)
        self.genreCombo.place(x=110, y=60)

        Label(
            text="___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________").place(
            x=0, y=85)

        Button(text="Display Movie(s)", command=self.createLabel).place(x=585, y=265, width=100)
        self.movieLabel = Label(text = "")
        self.movieLabel.place(x=60, y=160)

    def createLabel(self, event=None):
        self.movieLabel.configure(text=" | ".join(movies.get(self.updateHorror())))

w = 700
h = 300
x = 0
y = 0

app = Application()
app.master.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))
app.master.title("Cinema Booking")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahh, now I get it! Much appreciated mate!